# Best practice - warning: method lacks 'await' operator warning

Tags: c#, async-await

Yes, I know there are other questions to cover what this warning means and how to solve it, however, I have a question about best practices regarding async programming.

I have a service layer which handles data transfer between the data layer and the presentation layer. This service contains several methods which query the database, and return the result.

I have been trying to use async programming wherever possible. An example:

```
    public async Task<SiteTemplateResource[]> GetResources(int siteTemplateId, string extension)
    {
        return await Database.FindBy<SiteTemplateResource>(str => str.SiteTemplateId == siteTemplateId && str.HashedFile.EndsWith(extension)).ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

My problem with this is, I'm not actually awaiting anything, other than to the `ToArrayAsync` call, which I don't *really* need.

Should I go ahead and use async/await for this? And how would I for example await anything for this function:

```
    public async Task<int> SiteTemplateBySiteIdAsync(int siteId)
    {
        return Database.First<SiteSiteTemplate>(sst => sst.SiteId == siteId).SiteTemplateId;
    }
```

I don't await anything in that function, but I also don't need to call `ToArrayAsync`, so how do I avoid the warning "method lacks 'await' operator" in above case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have `ToArrayAsync`, your should have `FirstAsync` too. As for the first method - just remove async\await keywords. `ToArrayAsync` returns Task and your GetResources method returns Task - no need to use async\await here.

Comment: @Evk I didn't know that existed, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `async/await` if you return the result of the asynchronous operation. Just use `public Task<...> GetResources(..)=> return Database.FindBy.....ToArrayAsync();`

Comment: You can use `Where`, `Select`, and `FirstAsync` to keep the second method asynchronous too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have nothing to `await` in a method that needs to be `async` (for whatever reason), you can use `Task.FromResult`, which can be awaited:

```
public async Task<int> SiteTemplateBySiteIdAsync(int siteId)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(Database.First<SiteSiteTemplate>(sst => sst.SiteId == siteId).SiteTemplateId);
}
```

If you don't need the `async` method, you can simply more the `async Task<int>` and replace it for `int`.

Comment: Since you immediately return you can even remove the async and await keywords. As long as it retuns a Task everything will be fine.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I needed. When you say "a method that needs to be `async`", are you implying that not everything should be async? Currently my perspective is to make a function async whenever possible, but is that the right idea?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Sometimes you are bound to interfaces though, so you need to have them sometimes even if the code itself doesn't require it. Simply not making a method `async` when it doesn't need to is fine too.

Comment: But if you do use `async` in the lowest method, you need to go `async` all the way.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchornous api does not necessary need async\await keywords. First you should ask yourself if anything you call inside your method use IO and have asynchronous version of that IO api. In your case you try to access database, that is IO, your library has asynchronous version (`ToArrayAsync`), so all makes sense. Now check if you do anything else *after* calling that asynchronous api. If yes - use async\await. If not - just return the result back to the caller:

```
public Task<SiteTemplateResource[]> GetResources(int siteTemplateId, string extension)
{
    return Database.FindBy<SiteTemplateResource>(str => str.SiteTemplateId == siteTemplateId && str.HashedFile.EndsWith(extension)).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

In the second case you also try to access database, but you *think* that there is no async api to do that. Most likely that is not true, because if you have `ToArrayAsync` - it's very likely all database access methods have async version and so you should have `FirstAsync`. Then your method becomes:

```
public async Task<int> SiteTemplateBySiteIdAsync(int siteId)
{
    var result = await Database.FirstAsync<SiteSiteTemplate>(sst => sst.SiteId == siteId);
    return result.SiteTemplateId;
}
```

Here you do something after calling `FirstAsync`, so you need to use async\await keywords.

Comment: If you use `Where` and `Select` you won't need to `await`. The query may be more efficient too, if the provider returns only the `SiteTemplateId`. As it is, it would have to return the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

`async/await` are needed only if you want to process the results of an already asynchronous operation in the method itself. They don't make the method or the call asynchronous. If you *don't* need to process the Task result, you can just return it:

```
public Task<SiteTemplateResource[]> GetResources(int siteTemplateId, string extension)
{
    return Database.FindBy<SiteTemplateResource>(str => 
                           str.SiteTemplateId == siteTemplateId 
                           && str.HashedFile.EndsWith(extension))
                   .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

or, using an expression bodied method

```
public Task<SiteTemplateResource[]> GetResources(int siteTemplateId, string extension)=>
        Database.FindBy<SiteTemplateResource>(str => 
                        str.SiteTemplateId == siteTemplateId 
                        && str.HashedFile.EndsWith(extension))
                .ToArrayAsync();
```

You can avoid `async/await` in the second case as well and still keep it asynchronous, if you use `Where`,Select and `FirstAsync`:

```
public Task<int> SiteTemplateBySiteIdAsync(int siteId)=>
    Database.Where(sst => sst.SiteId == siteId)
            .Select(it=>it.SiteTemplateId)
            .FirstAsync();
}
```

This has the added advantage of returning *only* the ID from the database. If you didn't use `Select`, the provider would have to read the entire object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your code like bellow:

```
public int SiteTemplateBySiteIdAsync(int siteId)
{
    return Database.First<SiteSiteTemplate>(sst => sst.SiteId == siteId).SiteTemplateId;
}
```

Have a nice day!